# How does this function not break Java type safety requirements?

Tags: java, type-inference, type-safety

I was trying to figure out how some of the getParcelable() type functions in Android work and I was able to bundle my misunderstanding into this short snippet:

```
<T> T someFunction() {
    Object a = new Object();
    return (T)a;
}

void testSomeFunction() {
    String a = someFunction();
    List<Activity> activityLIst = someFunction();
    int[] intArray = someFunction();
}
```

Why does the compiler allow this? To me this appears to break type safety without the code calling the function ever having to cast the return value. Is seems like you could technically replace every single non 'void' return parameter with

```
<T> T
```

and it would compile fine (and run fine if you got it all right). Does anyone have any information on the peculiar format of the return parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course it breaks type safety, and all of the common Java compilers will at least output a warning on the cast `(T) a`.  Generally, though, the compiler can't always trace back to the creation of the object stored in `a` to prove it's *really* of the wrong type, so the compiler won't actually forbid this.

Comment: Why does the compiler allow a "this could be absolutely anything and I'll allow you to use it like absolutely anything" type argument without explicitly doing so in the code that calls it. Or better phrased, what use might the designers of Java envision that makes them decide this code should be compilable.

Comment: @Chad, there are many cases in which the compiler simply isn't smart enough to tell that your code is actually type-safe, so the compiler allows you to do unsafe casts, trusting the programmer to know what they're doing.  In this particular case it's obvious to a human that this can't work, but that's not true in general -- the human might know the cast will always be safe even if the compiler can't prove it itself.

Comment: @Chad The cast is a programmer's way of telling the compiler to shut up. When you do that, what do you expect?

Comment: @LouisWasserman The more I think about it, I can see how the compiler would probably write out these functions after inferring the type from the return type and it would just look like a normal unchecked cast at runtime. I hadn't seen this behavior of inferring types from return values so the flow of the logic just felt a little backwards at first. Thanks for taking the time to explain.